# Parentheses in Java

Tags: java

How can I make Java print a double variable (`discount`) inside of parentheses -e.g.- `(42.00% of your purchase)`?

When I type `System.out.println(discount + "(% of your purchase)");` the output does not include the variable that `discount` holds inside of the parentheses. It outputs `42.00(% of your purchase)`.

Comment: Java != javascript, please fix the tag

Answer (score 4):

```java
System.out.printf("(%.2f%% of your purchase)\n", discount);
```

Using String formats will help you include the variable in the string, but also format it with how many decimals you want.

In this case `%%` is a literal percent sign

`%.2f` means print the floating number with 2 decimal places.

(If you want more information on String formatting see the official spec here https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax or search around for a Java String Format Tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("(" + discount + "% of your purchase)");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 System.out.printf("(%f%% of your purchase)", discount);
```